# How to limit data entry to only lowercase letters in LiveCode?

Tags: livecode

I am making a two-player hangman game, and I have set a limit of 10 characters which is working fine:

```
on keyDown
 if the length of me = 10 then
  beep
 else
  pass keyDown
 end if
end keyDown
```

However, when I try to limit the character input to only lowercase characters, nothing seems to happen. I can still type any character I want.

```
on keyDown inkey
 if inkey is in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" then
  pass keyDown
 else
  beep
 end if
end keyDown
```

How do I fix this? Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass the `keyDown` message. Instead, put the value of the parameter after the field.

```
on keyDown theKey
  if len(the text of me) >= 10 then
    beep
  else
    put toLower(theKey) after me
  end if
end keyDown
```

The problem occurs, because LiveCode considers lower case and upper case characters as equal:

```
put ("a"="A")
```

returns true. Another way to solve this is to `set the caseSensitive to true`. If you add this line

```
set the caseSensitive to true
```

to the beginning of your script, it will do exactly what you want.